# Git: subtree or submodule for personal projects?

Tags: git, version-control

I have a git repo with various helpers and I want to use them in multiple personal projects. I've tried using subtree approach described in "Pro Git" book but had troubles updating the "Utils" repo. Should I use the submodules? All projects have single contributor (me) and are hosted at Github.

Answer (score 1):

Use submodules. If you find that you are updating your utils often, I would make use git slave. This will propagate commands into the submodule level.