# Submodule or Subtree for collaboration

Tags: git, git-submodules, git-subtree

> **TLDR**: I am unsure if I should be using a `subtree` or `submodule` and how to setup/use the appropriate solution.

## The current workflow

I have a private repository `A` which has several sub-directories (e.g. `a`) of my research, which only I have access to. Based on some of this work I wish to have a sub-set of this work (self contained in a sub-directory `b`) available in a "second" repository which a second author can use to make edits. Ideally this second repository should appear to the other author like a normal repository (a master branch, github page, etc.).

```
A       # Main git repo
├── a   # My private work
└── b   # Work I would like a collaborator to contribute to.
```

My collaborator editing `b` should not be able to access or view anything outside of `b`. Hence I am weary of accidentally having a change in `a` logged in `b` if I should commit both under a single commit under `A`, (cf. my point of concern about committing changes a few paragraphs below).

### A subdirectory should be a second repository for collaboration

If I make changes in `a` or `b` then I think this should be tracked in the `A` git log. If however I make changes only in `a` then this should not be tracked in `b`'s git log. If a collaborator should make changes in `b` then I should be able to pull these.

If I make some changes in both `a` and `b` in a single commit under `A`, then I am a bit unsure how best this should be handled and am open to suggestions/comments. For my case I think it is best if these are split into two separate commits as `b` is stand-alone within `A` and unrelated to `a`. If this requires extra vigilance on my part when committing then so be it, although if this is a common pitfall and gotcha that is a nightmare to disentangle then please advise.

### Subtree or submodule?

Based on a bit of reading (e.g. [How do I work with a git repository within another repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1811730/how-do-i-work-with-a-git-repository-within-another-repository)) I am struggling to differentiate between subtree and submodule, and either seem suitable. I'm not yet well versed enough to even differentiate the difference between these and the problems they are solving.

## Related questions

I think the following questions are related but I don't think they quite address my situation:

1. [git submodules, subtrees or else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54172820/git-submodules-subtrees-or-else)
2. [Git: subtree or submodule for personal projects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5482382/git-subtree-or-submodule-for-personal-projects)

> Currently [after some more reading](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31770145/5134817) I think a `subtree` may be the best fit, but I am still uncertain, (cf. [Differences between git submodule and subtree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31769820/differences-between-git-submodule-and-subtree?rq=1)).